# Отображение ошибок с помощью BindingResult в Thymeleaf форме при redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

У меня не отображаются ошибки, которые я вписал в `BindResult.rejectValue(...)` после `redirect`. Код сам рабочий и программа успешно принимает форму, успешно ее обрабатывает, но при `redirect` на другую (в данном случае, прошлую) страницу данные об ошибках не сохраняются. Как это исправить?

Код thymeleaf:

```html
<form th:action="@{/account/general/edit/name}" class="form-edit" method="post">
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('customer.name')}" class="form-edit">
        <span th:errors="*{customer.name}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Имя</span>
        <input type="text" th:value="${customer.name}" th:field="*{customer.name}">
    </div>
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('customer.surname')}" class="form-edit">
        <span th:errors="*{customer.surname}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Фамилия</span>
        <input type="text" th:value="${customer.surname}" th:field="*{customer.surname}">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

Java-контроллер для страницы выше:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account/general/edit")
public class GeneralInformationEditController {

    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView GeneralInformationEditGet(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        //некоторый код

        Customer customer = generalService.findByEmail(email);

        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);

        modelAndView.setViewName("account/edit/general_information_edit");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Java-контроллер на которую переходит форма:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/account/general/edit/name")
public class NameEdit {

    @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView NameEditPost(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customerForm, BindingResult bindingResult){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/account/general/edit");

        //checkers
        if(customerForm.getName().length() > 18 || customerForm.getName().length() < 2){

            //Недостаточно символов. Должно быть между 2 и 18
            bindingResult.
                    rejectValue("name", "error.name",
                            "Неправильное количество символов. Количество букв должно быть от 2 до 18.");
        }

        //checkers
        if(customerForm.getSurname().length() > 18 || customerForm.getSurname().length() < 2){

            //Недостаточно символов. Должно быть между 2 и 18
            bindingResult.
                    rejectValue("surname", "error.surname",
                            "Неправильное количество символов. Количество букв должно быть от 2 до 18.");
        }

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("ошибки");
            return modelAndView;
        }

        //некоторый код, если ошибок нет
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашел [на данном сайте](https://gerrytan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/preserving-validation-error-messages-on-spring-mvc-form-post-redirect-get/)

Все достаточно просто. Нужно просто было добавить:
 `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.NAMEOFTHEATTRIBUTE", bindingResult);`

```java
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
    redirectAttributes.getFlashAttributes().clear();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.customer", bindingResult);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("customer", customerForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

В GET-форме нужно изменить данную строку:

```java
model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
```

на данную:

```java
if(!model.containsAttribute("customer")){
  model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
}
```